# How to find out where arguments come from to the specific parameter in Java?

Tags: java, parameters, computer-science

I've come to wonder if there is a way to find out which method arguments are returned from.

If you have a few methods in a few classes, perhaps it's easier to figure out where the values come from to the parameter by looking at the method signature.

What if we have very complicated structure of classes? how can we efficiently figure it out? (other than using debugger)

I would appreciate your advice!

For example,

public class Recursion_fig18_9 {

```
//recursive declaration of method factorial
public static long factorial(long number){
    long result = 1;

    //iterative declaration of method factorial
    for (long i = number; i >=1; i--){
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}


//output factorials for values of 0 to 10
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //calculate the factorials from 0 to 10
    for (int counter =0; counter <= 10; counter ++){
        System.out.printf("%d! = %d%n", counter, factorial(counter));
    }
}
```

(Although this example is quite small structure of class,)
How can I figure out where "number" is returned from in the factorial method?

Comment: "which method arguments are returned from"? What does that mean? Could you give an example?

Comment: In general, in your code?  You can't.

Comment: this is a very confusingly worded question. What exactly are you looking to do? know where a method's parameters came from before the method call? Know the values of the parameters? please reword to get better answers.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking here. Your question does not contain grammatically correct english sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your debugger you can set a break point within the method.  When that method breaks, you'll see a stack frame indicating where the call to the method came from and this will help you to trace back the method call to figure out how it was constructed.

Within your code example, place the breakpoint on the `return` statement so that you can examine the return value before it is returned.

Alternatively, you could use a logger to generate a log file and see how your code steps through it.  You'd be able to back off the logging level after the fact so that you don't have to change code constantly.  More on logging [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html)

Comment: Id say this is a great attempt at deciphering the question lol

Comment: You could use a logger as well.  Lots of logging statements and then view the logs.  The debugger is just one way to do it, but it works.. thanks @RichardBarker :) years of tech support work and a babbelfish do wonders

Comment: @In-youngChoung I really would look into learning to use your IDE's built in debugger -- that will make life a million times easier and your code will look and feel cleaner.

Comment: @OYRM a babbelfish definitely helps. I have to get mine back from Ford but I have not seen nor heard a thing from him in years... I think he got stuck somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I am looking back at my old question and I am answering to my own question.

You can figure out easily without using debug which method calls the current method and passes the parameters by

1. selecting the current method
2. right mouse click
3. click Open Call Hierarchy (or Ctrl + Alt + H).